# Jquery Accordion Script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

При повторном нажатии, нужно чтобы закрывалось, в моем случае он заново раскрывается. Как предотвратить это?

```js
$('.accordion_button').click(function(event) {
  $('.item_content').slideUp(200);
  $(this).next('.item_content').slideToggle(200);
  
});
```

```css
.accordion_item{
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    
}
.accordion_button a{
    color:#fff;
    padding:0 15px;
    background-color: #0E6937;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.item_content{
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    background: #237E4C;
    
}
.item_content ul{
    margin: 0;
}
.item_content ul li a{
    padding-left: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
            <div class="accordion_list">
              <div class="accordion_item">
                <div class="accordion_button">
                  <a href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>My GoodGross
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="item_content">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">My (company) profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="extra">
                      <a href="#" class="toggle">
                        Contact info
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" 
                        style="margin-left:0.5rem;"></a>
                      <ul class="list_toggle">
                        <li><a href="#">Address</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Phone</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">My PayPal account</a></li>
                
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="accordion_item">
                <div class="accordion_button">
                  <a href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>Messages
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="item_content">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">My (company) profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="extra">
                      <a href="#" class="toggle">
                        Contact info
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" 
                        style="margin-left:0.5rem;"></a>
                      <ul class="list_toggle">
                        <li><a href="#">Address</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Phone</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">My PayPal account</a></li>
                
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="accordion_item">
                <div class="accordion_button">
                  <a href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>My Buying
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="item_content">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">My (company) profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="extra">
                      <a href="#" class="toggle">
                        Contact info
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" 
                        style="margin-left:0.5rem;"></span></a>
                      <ul class="list_toggle">
                        <li><a href="#">Address</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Phone</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">My PayPal account</a></li>
                
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="accordion_item">
                <div class="accordion_button">
                  <a href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span>My Selling
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="item_content">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Watching</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Best offers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Active</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pending</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                
                  </ul>
                </div>
                
              </div>
              <div class="accordion_item">
                <div class="accordion_button">
                  <a href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>Settings
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="item_content">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Edit Bank Account</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Set a security question</a></li>
                    
                  </ul>
                </div>
                
              </div>
              
            </div>  
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например:

```js
$('.accordion_button a').click(function(e) { // Клик на ссылку кнопки
  e.preventDefault();                        // Запрещаем переход по ссылке
  
  var $this = $(this),
      item = $this.closest('.accordion_item'), // Находим пункт в котором кнопка находится
      content = item.find('.item_content'),    // Находим контент именно внутри этого пункта
      contents = $('.item_content');           // Все контенты во всех пунктах
  
  if(!item.hasClass('open')){                  // Если пункт не открыт (нет класса open)
    contents.slideUp(200);                     // Сварачиваем все контенты
    item.addClass('open').siblings().removeClass('open');  // Открываем необходимый пункт (добавляем класс open), все остальные закрываем (у всех остальных удаляем класс open)
    content.slideDown(200);                    // Показываем контент именно этого пункта
  } else { 
    item.removeClass('open');                 // Иначе у всех убираем класс open и все контенты убираем
    contents.slideUp(200);
  }
  
});
```

```css
.accordion_item{
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    
}
.accordion_button a{
    color:#fff;
    padding:0 15px;
    background-color: #0E6937;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.item_content{
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    background: #237E4C;
    
}
.item_content ul{
    margin: 0;
}
.item_content ul li a{
    padding-left: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion_list">
    <div class="accordion_item">
      <div class="accordion_button">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>My GoodGross
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item_content">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">My (company) profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="extra">
            <a href="#" class="toggle">
              Contact info
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" 
                    style="margin-left:0.5rem;"></a>
              <ul class="list_toggle">
                <li><a href="#">Address</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Phone</a></li>
              </ul>
              </li>
          <li><a href="#">My PayPal account</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_item">
      <div class="accordion_button">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>Messages
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item_content">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">My (company) profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="extra">
            <a href="#" class="toggle">
              Contact info
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" 
                    style="margin-left:0.5rem;"></a>
              <ul class="list_toggle">
                <li><a href="#">Address</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Phone</a></li>
              </ul>
              </li>
          <li><a href="#">My PayPal account</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_item">
      <div class="accordion_button">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>My Buying
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item_content">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">My (company) profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="extra">
            <a href="#" class="toggle">
              Contact info
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" 
                    style="margin-left:0.5rem;"></span></a>
            <ul class="list_toggle">
              <li><a href="#">Address</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Phone</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">My PayPal account</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_item">
      <div class="accordion_button">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span>My Selling
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item_content">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Watching</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Best offers</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Active</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pending</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">History</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="accordion_item">
      <div class="accordion_button">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>Settings
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item_content">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Edit Bank Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Set a security question</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    $('.accordion_button').click(function(event) {
    $('.accordion_button').addClass('sleep');
    $(this).removeClass('sleep');
    $(this).next('.item_content').slideToggle(200);
    $('.accordion_button.sleep').next('.item_content').slideUp(200);
});
```

Присваиваем остальным элементам класс 'sleep'. С кнопки, на которую нажимаем убираем этот класс. Что-то типа булеана получается. Затем делаем `slideUp()`, для всех переведённых в спящие. Так как на щелкнутом элементе нет этого класса, он не сворачивается...

Comment: можете на примере показать, пожалуйста